# How to change backgroud color of ListItem after closing conxtext menu?

Tags: android, background-color, highlight, onlongclicklistener

I want to keep an item highlighted while I show a context (ie: `menu(displayed after a OnLongClick)`), and I want to un-highlight it after I choose an option or cancel it.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

on long click set the a variable to the row that is selected and in the adapter if the row is equal to the selected row set it to the highlighted item and then where you create your menu you can put this

```
@Override
public void onContextMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
    super.onContextMenuClosed(menu);
    //uncolor row
}
```

and remove the selected row int or set it to -1 then call notifiyDataSetChanged on the adapter